# How to use a string to map to an object key in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to assure if some object structure exist in the window object and if not exist create it.

My end Goal is to have this: `window.Debug.ObjectCategory`

I have a function that returns me a reference of `window` that is assured to contain `Debug` in it

```
interface MyWindow extends Window {
  Debug?: {
     [key in DebugCategories]?: {}
  }
}

enum DebugCategories {
  Category1 = 'Category1',
  Category2 = 'Category2',
}


function getWindowDebug(): Required<MyWindow> {
  if (!window.Debug) {
    window.Debug= {}
  }

  return window as Required<MyWindow>
}
```

but now I want to create a generic function where I can get a secure `window.Debug.Category1` or `window.Debug.Category2` but I can not figure out how to write the function return:

```
function getWindowWithCategory(category: DebugCategories ): Required<MyWindow > & WHAT_HERE? {
  const myWindow = getWindowDebug();

  if (!myWindow.Debug[category]) {
    window.Debug[category] = {}
  }

  return myWindow as ???;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return the specific category only, the entire `myWindow` object, or something else?

Comment: I just want to be sure the requested category exist. I do not care about the other ones because I do not want to create the category object if they are never used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it. I refactored the code some to make sure Debug is defined with its categories at the start, let me know if you are looking for a different return type for the `getWindowWithCategory` fn.

```js
enum DebugCategory {
  Category1 = 'Category1',
  Category2 = 'Category2',
}

type Debug = Record<DebugCategory, {}>;

interface DebugWindow extends Window {
  Debug: Debug;
}

function getDebugWindow(): DebugWindow {
  const debugWindow = window as unknown as DebugWindow;
  if (debugWindow.Debug) {
    return debugWindow;    
  }
  
  debugWindow.Debug = {
    [DebugCategory.Category1]: {},
    [DebugCategory.Category2]: {},
  };
  return debugWindow;
}

function getDebugWindowCategory<T extends DebugCategory>(category: T): Debug[T] {
  return getDebugWindow().Debug[category];
}
```